# Flutter has dely to update variable in showModalBottomSheet

Tags: flutter, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I recently have started to learn flutter from scratch by design an app restaurant delivery
I have faced with an strange problem
while i am adding/removeing food from showModalBottemSheet, it gets the number of food from server but has show it with delay. i show the total food in basket in main page and the result is true.
How Can i solve it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJYhX.png)

How do i use provider? in show modal?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtlZs.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Flutter Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) package to overcome this issue. Use a common provider to change and update value. That's how you can view the changes instantly!

Comment: i added more photo, how can i use provider in show modal bottom ?thanks

Comment: you can just access your provider instance via `Provider.of<YourProviderClass>(context);` if you have followed the instructions properly from the documentation

Comment: thank you but i found the simple way, so i used StateSetter